# Printing for a combined array to html

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 arrays that print out in a nice html format from search engines, here are the foreach loops for printing out

Bing API

```
foreach($jsonObj->d->results as $value){
            echo  "<a href=\"{$value->Url}\">{$value->Title}</a><p>{$value->Description}</p>". "<br>";

        }
```

Blekko API

```
foreach($js->RESULT as $item){
        echo  "<a href=\"{$item->url}\">{$item->url_title}</a><p>{$item->snippet}</p>". "<br>";

    }
```

Google API

```
foreach($all_items as $item){
        echo  "<a href=\"{$item->link}\">{$item->title}</a><p>{$item->snippet}</p>". "<br>";

    }
```

I then created a comnined array such as below

```
$combined = array(); 

foreach($bingArray as $key=>$value){ 
if(isset($combined[$key]))
$combined[$key]["score"] += $value['score']; 
  else
    $combined[$key] = array("score"=>$value['score'],"title"=>$value["title"], "snippet"=>$value   ["snippet"]); 
}
```

When I do a print_r($combined) i get the following output

```
Array ( [example.com] => Array ( [score] => 51 [title] => example title[snippet] => Blah baly... )[example2.com] => Array ( [score] => 45 [title] => example title2[snippet] => Blah baly2... ) ....)
```

This is fine and the same format as all 3 API arrays, now I'm trying to print out the combined array in html like the 3 API's and here is the code I tried

```
foreach($combined as $value){
            echo  "<a href=\"{$value->url}\">{$value->title}</a><p>{$value->snippet}</p>". "<br>";

            }
```

But when I run it I get this error "Trying to get property of non-object", I suspect that I need to change somthing in here "foreach($combined as $value)" but I not sure what, can anyone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you do not have objects anymore.

Change this:

```
foreach($combined as $value){
    echo "<a href=\"{$value->url}\">{$value->title}</a><p>{$value->snippet}</p>". "<br>";
}
```

To this:

```
foreach($combined as $url => $value){
    echo "<a href=\"{$url}\">{$value['title']}</a><p>{$value['snippet']}</p>". "<br>";
}
```

Comment: It nearly works, I'm getting "Undefined index: url " warning and the url won't connect

Comment: Ah well. I looked at your combined array again and in fact the "url" part is missing. Did you saw that?

Comment: If you look at the array,you will see how the combined array is structured

Comment: Yeah nearly there, but when I click on the link it trys to connect to the local server and not the internet

Comment: @user2634446: If not already the case you have to prepend a `http://` before $url.

Comment: the urls have been normalized so there is now, http:/ or www. but that shouldn't matter, when I click on a link with this it searchs for the webpage on the local server instead of th internet, the 3 APIs array's connect to internet no problem